# Clustered Index total fragmentation to high (66.67%)

Tags: sql-server-2005, clustered-index, database-indexes

i have a table with just 7 columns and 400 rows. There is a clustered Index on its Primary Key column. The index page Fullness is 68.98% and Total Fragmentation is 66.67%.

This is a table that i use in 90% of the application queries and i have a feeling its slowing down the quite alot of queries because of the high fragmentation percentage. Any advice?

Observation: Out of the 7 columns in the table, 3 columns completely have NULL value for all rows, could this be the cause?

Comment: What is the table definition? High levels of fragmentation are perfectly normal for small tables as the first few pages are allocated from mixed extents and you say it only has 400 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get meaningful fragmentation figures for tables that occupy just a few 8k data pages. The indexes take even less: I'd guess at 2 pages max for the index

Don't worry about it.